# Enable syncing DB dump between tenants in a multi-tenant Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, etl, pg-dump

Our Java application stores data pertaining to multiple tenants in one single DB instance on AWS RDS. This setup is replicated across regions in prod. There are multiple schemas and each table within those schemas have a tenantId field. It might not necessarily be the primary key but all tables have indices on the tenantId field.

Now the requirement is to select data stored for one tenant, across all tables and re-insert it with a different tenantId.

To clarify I have 3 tables `tableA`, `tableB`, `tableC` each containing `R rows` for `tenant_A`. Now a different `tenant_B` gets created in the system and the requirement is that each of the `R rows` across all three tables gets created in those 3 tables with `tenantId = tenant_B`. This has to happen as a bootstrap DB sync step before tenant_B starts with it's own lifecycle in our system.

One option I was considering to create an one time pg_dump of all the tables, upload it to S3, store it in per tenant buckets and whenever a new tenant (like tenant_B) comes, we restore from the respective SQLs for the parent tenant - `tenant_A` in our example by replacing tenantId field with `tenant_B` now (in all those inserts).

But the concern is the data we have is huge and to do a pg_dump daily might be un-necessary overloading the DB instance (if at all it has concerning overhead). I was looking if we can stream the incremental updates on top of the one-time dump and that way we keep the dump up-to-date. However, streaming WAL logs has it's own disadvantage - what if replication/streaming stops and the logs start filling up the DB storage? Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Another option is to fire pg_dump only when a child tenant (like `tenant_B` gets created). So that we trigger the dump for it's parent `tenant_A` upload it to S3 and restore it. However, with more and more concurrent tenants getting created in quick succession - this might not be a feasible solution in the long run.

**Why are we uploading pg_dump to S3** : As we might need to run it across Geo. As in the dump for `tenant_A` is from `us-west-2` and `tenant_B` might get created in `eu-central-1`. That's our internal logic that handles tenant creation and the region boundary is not guaranteed.

Any help here would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!